# iron fuctions: fn build for iron/go can't load package github.com/x/y

Tags: ironfunctions

I am trying to run basic commands given in https://github.com/iron-io/functions.
I created a fuc.go and funct.yaml file successfully but when I try to execute fn build, I get below error:

Running prebuild command: docker run --rm -v /home/evr:/go/src/github.com/x/y -w /go/src/github.com/x/y iron/go:dev go build -o func
can't load package: package github.com/x/y: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: swap_sll.c
error running docker build: exit status 1

Comment: You may want to add golang and docker tags.

Answer (score 0):

I got the cause for the above issue
Actually it was looking for data directory of iron function which I had specified a specific path instead of ${PWD} and was executing fn build in another working dirctory. So have to execute fn build in that directory where data directory is present (specific path which I specified).